How to type function which returns associated type so that it works in subclass?
I have a class Foo which has a to_bar method which returns Bar. I also have a subclass MyFoo for which to_bar returns MyBar (a subclass of Bar). Foo has quite a lot of methods which can return Bar, and for each one of these, the corresponding method on MyFoo should return MyBar.
Here's what I've written:
from __future__ import annotations

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    @property
    def _bar(self) -> type[Bar]:
        return Bar

    def to_bar(self) -> Bar:
        return self._bar(self.value)

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class MyFoo(Foo):
    @property
    def _bar(self) -> type[MyBar]:
        return MyBar

class MyBar(Bar):
    ...

print(type(Foo(3).to_bar()))
print(type(MyFoo(3).to_bar()))

It outputs
$ python t.py
<class '__main__.Bar'>
<class '__main__.MyBar'>

which is correct. All good so far.
BUT, if I add
reveal_type(Foo(3).to_bar())
reveal_type(MyFoo(3).to_bar())

to the end of the file and run mypy on it, I get
$ mypy t.py
t.py:28: note: Revealed type is "t.Bar"
t.py:29: note: Revealed type is "t.Bar"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file

How can I type to_bar such that the return value is going to be correct for MyFoo.to_bar? I could overwrite to_bar in MyFoo, but doing so for every method which returns Bar in Foo would be tedious and error-prone

This question is very common; you want a generic: class Foo[B: Bar = Bar]: ... / class MyFoo(Foo[MyBar]): .... There should be a good dupe somewhere.

it might be common, but I couldn't find it, and didn't know what to search for...I'm surprised that this question was downvoted to be honest

(Not my downvote) It is due to the commonness that it's hard to find one; askers are often inexperienced with static typing in general, so the titles are not very searchable.

may I suggest that you've misunderstood the question and that it's not as common as you're thinking? if you try to write a solution you might realise there's a subtlety you're missing

I see you are asking about higher-kinded types as well. Expressing a relationship within the static type system is a very common question, and so are HKTs. It's a tad easier to find dupes for the latter: How to use Generic (higher-level) type variables in type hinting system?, Typing for a Python function that takes a generic class and returns a specific instance of that class (unanswered), Abstracting over type constructors in Python via type annotations, etc.
